# Error ng build when install in angular ng-block-ui

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an error when in my project angular run `ng build --prod` if I had install `ng-block-ui` library and used it `in app.module.ts`.
The error is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/BoundNodeCallbackObservable.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9341:18)
    at assignContextualParameterTypes (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41652:25)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41948:29)
    at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42959:28)
    at checkExpression (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42779:38)
    at checkReturnStatement (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45418:54)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46763:28)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
    at checkBlock (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44563:16)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46742:28)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethodDeferred (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41990:21)
    at checkDeferredNodes (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46828:25)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46863:17)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46842:13)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/bindNodeCallback.js 2:36-76
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/bindNodeCallback.js
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js
 @ ./node_modules/ng-block-ui/lib/services/block-ui-instance.service.js
 @ ./node_modules/ng-block-ui/lib/components/block-ui/block-ui.component.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/BoundCallbackObservable.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9341:18)
    at assignContextualParameterTypes (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41652:25)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41948:29)
    at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42959:28)
    at checkExpression (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42779:38)
    at checkReturnStatement (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45418:54)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46763:28)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
    at checkBlock (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44563:16)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46742:28)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethodDeferred (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41990:21)
    at checkDeferredNodes (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46828:25)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46863:17)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46842:13)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\HE CONNECT\HeConnect\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/bindCallback.js 2:32-68
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/bindCallback.js
 @ ./node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js
 @ ./node_modules/ng-block-ui/lib/services/block-ui-instance.service.js
 @ ./node_modules/ng-block-ui/lib/components/block-ui/block-ui.component.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

---

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sociallike",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "extract": "ngx-translate-extract --marker __ --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/en.json ./src/assets/i18n/it.json --clean --sort --format namespaced-json "
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "3": "^2.1.0",
    "3.0.0": "^3.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.0",
    "md2": "0.0.29",
    "messageformat": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "ng-block-ui": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.11",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^8.1.3",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.4",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^2.3.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Can I resolve it? Thanks to help

Comment: Somewhere in the code you added is something called '.type' that you have not yet defined. Search in that code for .type

Comment: WHat is the rxjs version ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek rxjs version is 5.5.2

Comment: And what's the version of `ng-block-ui` ? can u share your package.json ? it would help me get answers quickly

Comment: @ShashankVivek i have edited the question with package.json

Comment: i have solved downgrading ng-block-ui lib to version 1.0.4.Thanks